# Offsetting an ultrasonic receiver's signal for an amplifier with a floating ground

Tags: operational-amplifier, bias, receiver, ultrasound, transducer

I have an ultrasonic receiver that I'm putting through an amplifier. I've created a floating ground for the amplifier (because I want to pretend having a negative voltage supply). However, to achieve this I will need to offset my receiver signal by the floating ground voltage. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Grounding the receiver to the floating ground has not biased the receiver to the floating ground voltage. The receiver I am using is the 328SR160, and the input I am expecting is around 32kHz at 50mV.

My current circuit, assuming I manage to get the receiver bias working.[image: V1 is the incoming signal from the receiver. V4 represents the bias voltage, set to 7.5V.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bias the input of the opamp with resistors to the correct level then couple the input signal with a capacitor. The capacitor in conjunction forms a high-pass filter. The cutoff frequency needs to be lower than the signal frequency. The time constant will affect how quickly the circuit becomes usable at power-on and may limit how low the cutoff frequency can be.

The input capacitor (C1) prevents the bias voltage being affected by the DC voltage at the output of the transducer.  (Since a piezo-electric ultrasonic sensor is non-conductive the capacitor is not really necessary in this particular case although the simulation requires it as the voltage source is DC conductive)

Image credit: [https://www.electronics-notes.com](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/analogue_circuits/operational-amplifier-op-amp/non-inverting-amplifier.php)

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask what is the exact purpose of C1? I know you said they weren't necessary but I'd like to know what benefit they may yield.

Comment: @HFOrangefish - in your simulation the voltage source would conduct DC and force the voltage at the input of the amplifier to be ground, so the capacitor is necessary.